# Can not turn on my computer anymore

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I am trying to install dual systems on my new computer.

I have just installed windows10pro on my computer and I shrink the storage(C:) to half half. I plug in the usb for installing ubuntu and restart the computer. Then I click on the option install ubuntu. But it gives full screen error. I restart the computer and choose another options, check disks for defects, I got again full screen errors and I power off.

But this time when I try to power on, my computer gives me no reaction. Anyone could tell me what I could do now?

Best
Yumin

Comment: Can you get into your computer's BIOS?  Google how to do this if necessary, then set the boot device in the BIOS to the H/Disk that has Windows on it.  See if you can get Windows to boot and shut down a couple of times.  If successful, revert to trying to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you be more specific about these "full screen error" or "full screen errors"? Did you take a photo of any of these many errors?

Comment: "Check disk for defects" does not seem like part of the Ubuntu installer. How did you reach this option?

Comment: @user535733: I imagine the "Check disk for defects" is a Windows prompt, wanting confirmation that it should run ChkDsk before it boots into the gui.

Comment: No, I can not turn on the computer at all and so as the BIOS....:(

Comment: If you poweron your system, and the system does not pass POST (Power On Self Test), then you have hardware failure, nothing Ubuntu can do about it. Do you have hardware failure?

Comment: @MartynA, yes I suspected that too, hence the question.